# How format different values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, numbers

i have a columns of dataframe with 1000+ different format of values.
how can i format these in order to have unified view like this 1.000.000.

```
 Sales 
1.000.000
10000000
150,250
0,200655
```

for example:

- row 1 is desiderated view
- row 2 10000000 should be 10.000.000
- row 3 150,250 should be 150.250
- row 4 0,200655 should be 200.655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your input this should work:

```py
df['Sales'] = ["{:,}".format(int(num.replace('.', '').replace(',', ''))).replace(',', '.') for num in df['Sales']]
```

Here we:

1. get each element in *Sales* column and remove ',' and '.' ie '150,250' -> '150250'
2. Then covert the string into `int` ie '150250' -> 150250
3. then use `"{:,}".format()` to format `int` to string with commas ie 150250 -> '150,250'
4. In this converted string we replace commas ',' with period '.' ie '150,250' -> '150.250'
5. make an array with the results and assign it to Sales column of Dataframe

**Input:**

```
       Sales
0  1.000.000
1   10000000
2    150,250
3   0,200655
```

**Output:**

```
        Sales
0   1.000.000
1  10.000.000
2     150.250
3     200.655
```

Comment: ok thanks.but i still have 2 value not good-> 0,1 with your code give me 1(should be 100.000)...and another value 0,255 give me 255(should be 255.000)

Comment: @Domec, Hi I don't understand the logic behind that conversion. How does 1 become 100.000 but 255 become 255.000.

Comment: Do you know How can i trasform 1 into 100.000 and 255 into 255.000 in my column? Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @Domec why not multiply by 1000, use `"{:,}".format()` to get 100,000, then replace the comma with period using `.replace(',', '.')` to get 100.000.